# How are Dunkl operators used in Hamiltonian mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hamiltonian-formalism, representation-theory, lie-algebra

I am currently doing a math research project on the representation theory of Cherednik (double affine Hecke) algebras, specifically the algebra $\mathcal{H}_{t,c}(\mathfrak{S}_n,\mathfrak{h})$, which is an algebra generated by Dunkl operators and some group elements. (see [Lecture notes on Cherednik Algebras](https://arxiv.org/abs/1001.0432))

I am curious about the physical aspects of this algebra/operators, since I have heard that Dunkl operators arise naturally in the Hamiltonian mechanics of quantum systems. As someone not very well versed in physics (and since every resource I was able to find is research level), I would appreciate a "simpler" explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this all has definitely something to do with 2D CFT. Actually, Knizhnik-Zamolodchikov equations are mentioned on the page 43 of the link you provided. If you're not familiar with this topic, [di Francesco](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387947853) is the Bible, [Blumenhagen](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783642004490) is a short intro.

Besides this, it's been [long noticed](http://inspirehep.net/record/333422) that equations similar to 2D CFT arise in the context of 1D quasi-exactly solvable (QES) QM models. [Here](http://inspirehep.net/record/472850), in Section 8, the Calogero model is discussed in quite detail. All these topics are quite intriguing from the mathematical perspective. We probably still don't have a deep understanding of relations between QES QM models and 2D CFT.